# Mapbox GL using react-mapbox-gl on a create react app is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, mapbox-gl

I'm using Create react app to bootstrap my React JS application. I have integrated Mapbox GL via `react-mapbox-gl`.

My package.json has these two dependencies for mapbox (other dependencies were omitted):

```
  "dependencies": {
   "mapbox-gl": "^0.38.0",
   "react-mapbox-gl": "^1.12.0",
  }
```

Mapbox works as expected on `localhost:3000` but not in my production build on `localhost:8000`. I use `npm run start` to build my project.

Here is what it looks like in 8000 production: [mapbox not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zOK3.png)

Here is what it looks like in 3000 development: [expected map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRfY0.png)

The error I get exactly 9 times is: 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-mapbox-gl version 2.* should work with create-react-app. You can have a look at [react-mapbox-gl-debug](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl-debug) which is a boilerplate using create-react-app for react-mapbox-gl.